# How do you set the configuration bits for a PIC 16F1829 in MPLAB X?

Tags: pic

I am new to PIC programming (but not C, embedded systems, etc.)  I am using MPLAB X with the PIC16F1829 specified for the project.  I have the following includes:

```
#include <htc.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <pic16f1829.h>

__CONFIG( WDTDIS );  // No matter what I use in this macro, it won't build
```

I cannot seem to locate and definitions that work in the __CONFIG macro. The documentation also mentions `#pragma config SOMESETTING`, but I also cannot find any settings that will work. Does anyone know if:

- I am missing some setting or include in my project? Or,
- if settings that will work with this processor are documented somewhere?

UPDATE:

For anyone else who finds this, based on the documentation, for this processor with XC8, the correct way to specify these bits is with the `#pragma config`

```
#pragma config WDTE=OFF
#pragma config FOSC=INTOSC
```

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: Microchip XC8, Hi-Tech PICC or other? And what version of it? (That matters too)

Comment: It's Microchip XC8.  Based on the answer selected below, the location of the information for this compiler is currently located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.10\docs`.  Thanks, all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microchip's website has a document named [Using the right Format, Syntax and Definitions for PICmicro Configuration Bits](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC%20Config%20bit%20Format_Syntax_AndDefinitions.pdf) that explains where to find the configuration settings for your particular device.

For example it states for the PIC16F1 devices with a C Compiler:

> C Compiler:
>
> Format: Defined in the User Manual Located at:
>   C:\Program Files\HI‐TECH Software\PICC\\docs\
>
> Definition/Syntax: Located in respective product's header file.  Use
>   the pic16f1xxx.h header file at:
>   C:\Program Files\HI‐TECH Software\PICC\\include\

If we look in the header file for your particular chip we find:

```
/
// Configuration mask definitions
//


// Config Register: CONFIG1
#define CONFIG1              0x8007
// Oscillator Selection
// ECH, External Clock, High Power Mode (4-32 MHz): device clock supplied to CLKIN pin
#define FOSC_ECH             0xFFFF
// ECM, External Clock, Medium Power Mode (0.5-4 MHz): device clock supplied to CLKIN pin
#define FOSC_ECM             0xFFFE
// ECL, External Clock, Low Power Mode (0-0.5 MHz): device clock supplied to CLKIN pin
#define FOSC_ECL             0xFFFD
// INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin
#define FOSC_INTOSC          0xFFFC
// EXTRC oscillator: External RC circuit connected to CLKIN pin
#define FOSC_EXTRC           0xFFFB
// HS Oscillator, High-speed crystal/resonator connected between OSC1 and OSC2 pins
#define FOSC_HS              0xFFFA
// XT Oscillator, Crystal/resonator connected between OSC1 and OSC2 pins
#define FOSC_XT              0xFFF9
// LP Oscillator, Low-power crystal connected between OSC1 and OSC2 pins
#define FOSC_LP              0xFFF8
// Watchdog Timer Enable
// WDT enabled
#define WDTE_ON              0xFFFF
// WDT enabled while running and disabled in Sleep
#define WDTE_NSLEEP          0xFFF7
// WDT controlled by the SWDTEN bit in the WDTCON register
#define WDTE_SWDTEN          0xFFEF
// WDT disabled
#define WDTE_OFF             0xFFE7
// Power-up Timer Enable
// PWRT disabled
#define PWRTE_OFF            0xFFFF
// PWRT enabled
#define PWRTE_ON             0xFFDF
// MCLR Pin Function Select
// MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR
#define MCLRE_ON             0xFFFF
// MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input
#define MCLRE_OFF            0xFFBF
// Flash Program Memory Code Protection
// Program memory code protection is disabled
#define CP_OFF               0xFFFF
// Program memory code protection is enabled
#define CP_ON                0xFF7F
// Data Memory Code Protection
// Data memory code protection is disabled
#define CPD_OFF              0xFFFF
// Data memory code protection is enabled
#define CPD_ON               0xFEFF
// Brown-out Reset Enable
// Brown-out Reset enabled
#define BOREN_ON             0xFFFF
// Brown-out Reset enabled while running and disabled in Sleep
#define BOREN_NSLEEP         0xFDFF
// Brown-out Reset controlled by the SBOREN bit in the BORCON register
#define BOREN_SBODEN         0xFBFF
// Brown-out Reset disabled
#define BOREN_OFF            0xF9FF
// Clock Out Enable
// CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin
#define CLKOUTEN_OFF         0xFFFF
// CLKOUT function is enabled on the CLKOUT pin
#define CLKOUTEN_ON          0xF7FF
// Internal/External Switchover
// Internal/External Switchover mode is enabled
#define IESO_ON              0xFFFF
// Internal/External Switchover mode is disabled
#define IESO_OFF             0xEFFF
// Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable
// Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled
#define FCMEN_ON             0xFFFF
// Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled
#define FCMEN_OFF            0xDFFF


// Config Register: CONFIG2
#define CONFIG2              0x8008
// Flash Memory Self-Write Protection
// Write protection off
#define WRT_OFF              0xFFFF
// 000h to 1FFh write protected, 200h to 1FFFh may be modified by EECON control
#define WRT_BOOT             0xFFFE
// 000h to FFFh write protected, 1000h to 1FFFh may be modified by EECON control
#define WRT_HALF             0xFFFD
// 000h to 1FFFh write protected, no addresses may be modified by EECON control
#define WRT_ALL              0xFFFC
// PLL Enable
// 4x PLL enabled
#define PLLEN_ON             0xFFFF
// 4x PLL disabled
#define PLLEN_OFF            0xFEFF
// Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable
// Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset
#define STVREN_ON            0xFFFF
// Stack Overflow or Underflow will not cause a Reset
#define STVREN_OFF           0xFDFF
// Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection
// Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 1.9V
#define BORV_LO              0xFFFF
// Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 2.7V
#define BORV_HI              0xFBFF
// Low-Voltage Programming Enable
// Low-voltage programming enabled
#define LVP_ON               0xFFFF
// High-voltage on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming
#define LVP_OFF              0xDFFF
```

An example in the previously quoted document is:

```
__CONFIG(FOSC_INTOSC &WDTE_OFF &  PWRTE_OFF & MCLRE_ON& CP_OFF & BOREN_OFF & CLKOUTEN_ON & IESO_OFF & FCMEN_OFF); 
__CONFIG(WRT_OFF & VCAPEN_OFF & PLLEN_OFF & STVREN_OFF & LVP_OFF);
```

Comparing this with the above header file you can see what each configuration macro will enable/disable.

Answer (score 12):

In MPLABX there is another great option, there is an interactive code generation tool which produces code to copy and paste in. This tool can be accessed through the menu bar: Window/PIC memory views/configuration bits.
from there it looks similar to below.

**Address|Name    __ *_*   |Value|      Field |Option     |     Category__ _ _ _ *_*_|  Setting**
       _
300001  _|CONFIG1H _| 07 _ _ |OSC_ |RCIO6_ |Oscillator Selection bits|External RC oscillator

simply select your options from the option drop down boxes and view the changes on the settings column.
When all are set click "Generate Source Code To Output" then copy and paste

justing's method is better for learning the part, this method allows new users to get up and running more quickly. Take your pick.

Comment: The Generate Source Code To Output method is good . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

MPLAB X allows generating Config macros for your code.

Under MPLAB X IDE go to:
Windows >> PIC Memory View >> Configuration Bits >> This will open the Configuration Window 
Set the Config Macros in the right most column, under the 'Setting' column.

Then Click on "Generate Source Code to Output" button on bottom of the Configuration Memory Window.

This will print the Config Macros to a new Window - "Config Bits Source".
Copy the contents of this Config Source Window and paste it to the file which contains the main routine as shown below:

```
#pragma config XYZ

#include <xc.h>

void main ()
{
.
.
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed fresh MPLAB X IDE v5.35  and XC8 compiler and you need a tool to set those bits,**Configuration Bits** tool is in the :

Production >> SET Configuration Bits.

Then it opens a window which Cyclops answer shows, then if you click on **Generate source code** it will generate a file that you can add to your project , it is some thing like:

```
// PIC16F1459 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = ECH       // Oscillator Selection Bits (ECH, External Clock, High Power Mode (4-20 MHz): device clock supplied to CLKIN pins)
#pragma config WDTE = ON        // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset enabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = ON        // Internal/External Switchover Mode (Internal/External Switchover Mode is enabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config CPUDIV = CLKDIV6 // CPU System Clock Selection Bit (CPU system clock divided by 6)
#pragma config USBLSCLK = 48MHz // USB Low SPeed Clock Selection bit (System clock expects 48 MHz, FS/LS USB CLKENs divide-by is set to 8.)
#pragma config PLLMULT = 3x     // PLL Multipler Selection Bit (3x Output Frequency Selected)
#pragma config PLLEN = ENABLED  // PLL Enable Bit (3x or 4x PLL Enabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LPBOR = OFF      // Low-Power Brown Out Reset (Low-Power BOR is disabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming enabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
```

- **Be careful**, Your program would **NOT** work without setting these pins!